# Merging pandas DataFrames with deleting some part of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have these two dictionaries, that I would like to merge, but without deleting data of `a`, but deleting the non-matching values of `b`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'coname': ['Apple','Microsoft','JPMorgan','Facebook','Intel','McKinsey'],
    'eva': [20, 18, 73, 62, 56, 92],
    'ratio': [4, 7, 1, 6, 9, 8]
    })

b = pd.DataFrame({'coname': ['Apple','Microsoft','JPMorgan','Netflix','Total','Ford'],
     'city': ['Cupertino','Seattle','NYC','Palo Alto','Paris', 'Detroit'],
    'state': ['CA','WA','NY','CA','Ile de France', 'MI']
    })
```

I want to following output: EDITED

```
     coname   eva  ratio       city          state
0      Apple  20.0    4.0  Cupertino             CA
1  Microsoft  18.0    7.0    Seattle             WA
2   JPMorgan  73.0    1.0        NYC             NY
3   Facebook  62.0    6.0        NaN            NaN
4      Intel  56.0    9.0        NaN            NaN
5   McKinsey  92.0    8.0        NaN            NaN
```

I have tried

```
a = pd.merge(a,b, on = 'coname', how='outer')
for i in a['coname']:
    if i in b['coname']:
        a.drop(i)
```

with but I only get this:

```
      coname   eva  ratio       city          state
0      Apple  20.0    4.0  Cupertino             CA
1  Microsoft  18.0    7.0    Seattle             WA
2   JPMorgan  73.0    1.0        NYC             NY
3   Facebook  62.0    6.0        NaN            NaN
4      Intel  56.0    9.0        NaN            NaN
5   McKinsey  92.0    8.0        NaN            NaN
6    Netflix   NaN    NaN  Palo Alto             CA
7      Total   NaN    NaN      Paris  Ile de France
8       Ford   NaN    NaN    Detroit             MI
```

Answer (score 0):

`how='left'` will do the trick:

```
pd.merge(a,b, on = 'coname', how='left')
```

Result:

|  | coname | eva | ratio | city | state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple | 20 | 4 | Cupertino | CA |
| 1 | Microsoft | 18 | 7 | Seattle | WA |
| 2 | JPMorgan | 73 | 1 | NYC | NY |
| 3 | Facebook | 62 | 6 | nan | nan |
| 4 | Intel | 56 | 9 | nan | nan |
| 5 | McKinsey | 92 | 8 | nan | nan |